# Cannot be cast to java.lang.String error at WrapperClassOutInterceptor when connecting SOAP endpoint through Camel cxf component

Tags: java, soap, apache-camel, camel-cxf

I'm doing an implementation to call a SOAP web service and process the response.

I started from below post and I got below error when it is connected to the web service endpoint

- https://tomd.xyz/articles/camel-soap-service/
- https://tomd.xyz/articles/wsdl/

Error : "com.cleverbuilder.bookservice.GetBook cannot be cast to java.lang.String" at WrapperClassOutInterceptor.

What could be the reason for this?

Please note that http://localhost:8423/test/BookService is up and it is working fine. I tested outside the SOAP Router and it works fine there.

Like to highlight below at the logs

- BodyType: com.cleverbuilder.bookservice.GetBook,
- Body:

  > ```
  > <?xml
  >    version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><ns2:GetBook
  >    xmlns:ns2="http://www.cleverbuilder.com/BookService/">   
  >    <ID>12345</ID></ns2:GetBook>,
  > ```
- Out: null

**Log :**

```
06:28:32,381 INFO  [output >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> 5] (default task-1) Exchange[Id: ID-namal-pc-1569977860461-1-1, ExchangePattern: InOut, Properties: {CamelCreatedTimestamp=Wed Oct 02 06:28:32 IST 2019, CamelExternalRedelivered=false, CamelFilterMatched=true, CamelMessageHistory=[DefaultMessageHistory[routeId=route7, node=choice8], DefaultMessageHistory[routeId=route7, node=to23], DefaultMessageHistory[routeId=route5, node=to11], DefaultMessageHistory[routeId=route5, node=setBody1], DefaultMessageHistory[routeId=route5, node=to12], DefaultMessageHistory[routeId=route5, node=bean1], DefaultMessageHistory[routeId=route5, node=to13], DefaultMessageHistory[routeId=route5, node=setHeader1], DefaultMessageHistory[routeId=route5, node=to14], DefaultMessageHistory[routeId=route5, node=setHeader2], DefaultMessageHistory[routeId=route5, node=to15]], CamelToEndpoint=log://output%20%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%205?showAll=true}, Headers: {breadcrumbId=ID-namal-pc-1569977860461-1-1, clientId=magnify, doLogFiles=false, dontLogErrorFiles=false, messageId=soapExecutor, messageName=SOAPExecutor, operationName=GetBook, operationNamespace=http://www.cleverbuilder.com/BookService/, routeId=direct-soap, specialRq=true, uber-trace-id=, uberctx-user-name=null, useCommonService=false}, BodyType: com.cleverbuilder.bookservice.GetBook, Body: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><ns2:GetBook xmlns:ns2="http://www.cleverbuilder.com/BookService/">    <ID>12345</ID></ns2:GetBook>, Out: null: ]
06:28:32,424 WARNING [org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain] (default task-1) Interceptor for {http://www.cleverbuilder.com/BookService/}BookServicePortImplService#{http://www.cleverbuilder.com/BookService/}GetBook has thrown exception, unwinding now: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: com.cleverbuilder.bookservice.GetBook cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.interceptors.WrapperClassOutInterceptor.handleMessage(WrapperClassOutInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:537)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:439)
    at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfProducer.process(CxfProducer.java:133)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:148)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:138)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:101)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
    at org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectBlockingProducer.process(DirectBlockingProducer.java:53)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:148)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.ChoiceProcessor.process(ChoiceProcessor.java:117)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
    at org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectBlockingProducer.process(DirectBlockingProducer.java:53)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SharedCamelInternalProcessor.process(SharedCamelInternalProcessor.java:186)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SharedCamelInternalProcessor.process(SharedCamelInternalProcessor.java:86)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache$1.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:541)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache$1.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:506)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:369)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.sendExchange(ProducerCache.java:506)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.send(ProducerCache.java:264)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.requestBodyAndHeaders(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:355)
```

SoapRouter.java
@ApplicationScoped
@ContextName("camel_cdi_context")
public class SoapRouter extends RouteBuilder {

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {

    from("direct:soap")

        .to("log:output >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> 1?showAll=true")
            .setBody(constant("12345"))

        .to("log:output >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> 2?showAll=true")
            .bean(GetBookRequestBuilder.class)

        .to("log:output >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> 3?showAll=true")
            .setHeader(CxfConstants.OPERATION_NAME, constant("GetBook"))

        .to("log:output >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> 4?showAll=true")
            .setHeader(CxfConstants.OPERATION_NAMESPACE, constant("http://www.cleverbuilder.com/BookService/"))

        .to("log:output >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> 5?showAll=true")

        .to("cxf://http://localhost:8423/test/BookService?serviceClass=com.cleverbuilder.bookservice.BookService&wsdlURL=/wsdl/BookService.wsdl")

        .to("log:output >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> 6?showAll=true");

}
```

}

GetBookRequestBuilder.java
public class GetBookRequestBuilder {

```
public GetBook getBook(String id) {
    GetBook request = new GetBook();
    request.setID(id);

    return request;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I figured out one option with dataFormat=PAYLOAD as mentioned below. Anyway open for more options.

For SoapJaxbDataFormat, you will need to import camel-soap dependency.

eg :

```
String WS_URI = "cxf://http://myserver/customerservice?serviceClass=com.example.customerservice&dataFormat=MESSAGE";
SoapJaxbDataFormat soapDF = new SoapJaxbDataFormat("com.example.customerservice", new ServiceInterfaceStrategy(CustomerService.class));
from("direct:customerServiceClient")
  .onException(Exception.class)
    .handled(true)
    .unmarshal(soapDF)
  .end()
  .marshal(soapDF)
  .to(WS_URI)
  .unmarshal(soapDF);
```